# Process.Start throws Win32 Exception Access is Denied on Windows XP Machines

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm attempting to call an executable using `Process.Start` and it is throwing a Win32 Exception only on Windows XP machines.  This is a console application installed on the machine.

Here's an example of the code:

```
var path = @"C:\mycoolpath\file.exe";
var content = "My cool content";

using (var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(path, content)))
       process.WaitForExit();
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

Does anyone have any advice on getting this to work on Windows XP machines?

Comment: Totally wild guess, but perhaps you should grant it access so it will no longer be denied access?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET app or a Win32 service?

Comment: What kind of application it is form where you are calling this code? Is it a windows service?

Comment: Under which user it is failing? Do you run under admin or user account? "throwing a Win32 Exception only on Windows XP machines" - does it mean that under ie. WinServer, Win7 it is running properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `UseShellExecute = false` for the `ProcessStartInfo` lets this work.